# How to solve Android GCM 401 Error?

Tags: zend-framework, google-cloud-messaging

Have setup a project at Google Code APis console and have a server key at "Key for server apps (with IP locking)". I'am trying to send a push notification to GCM device using "API key" and one registration ID that I have stored at database.

For server side I'am using Zend_Mobile_Push_Gcm and have something like this:

```
$token = 'REGISTRATION ID';
$apiKey = 'API KEY';

//Send test push
$message = new Zend_Mobile_Push_Message_Gcm();
$message->setId(time());
$message->addToken($token);
$message->setData(array('foo' => 'bar', 'bar'=>'foo'));

$gcm = new Zend_Mobile_Push_Gcm();
$gcm->setApiKey($apiKey);

try {
    $response = $gcm->send($message);
} catch (Zend_Mobile_Push_Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

On the app side, I have used the GCM demo, that is currently registering it's registration ID on a server service.

I'am not able to send the push, always get a 401 error. Have gone through troubleshooting and tried my API KEY and Registration ID with the CLI test line at http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#auth_error but with no success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have now created an extra server key for my local IP and it worked, but it's still not working for the server where I need to deploy the application.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this was posted a while ago but be sure to use your server API key and not your android API key.

I had the same issue when trying to use my Android API key from PHP with Zend.